# codeigniter form validation in dropdown list

Tags: forms, codeigniter, validation, drop-down-menu

Hello I am new to codeigniter framework and I have a problem with form validation and dropdown lists.

My dropdown list is filled with data from database.

I don't know how to "remember" data in that list, after form validation.
I would like that my checked option somehow stay marked!

Can somebody help me with that!

Comment: Take a look at the `set_select` method within the form helper. http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/form_helper.html#set_select

Answer (score 0):

Is your dropdown a HTML select attribute?

```
<select> 
    <option>Yes</option>
    <option>No</option>
</select>
```

Then make sure to add value's to each OPTION and give a name to the select like below:

```
<select name="status">
    <option value="1">Yes</option>
    <option value="0">No</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I do it...

1. Before the call to the view (in the controller), I get the data from the database into the data variable 
    $data['class_list'] = $this->ClassDB->get_class_list();

   2. In the view you have the following code :

      ```
                 <select name="StuClass" id="StuClassId"> 
              <option value=""></option> <?php 
              foreach (class_list as $class) {
                  if (strcmp($student->Class, $class) == 0) {
                    printf("<option value='%s'     SELECTED>%s</option>\n", $class, $class);
                  } else {
                    printf("<option value='%s' >%s</option>\n", $class, $class);
                  }
              }?>
      ```

(apologies, I seem to have a problem correctly placing the php open-close tags here.)

3. After the form_validation $this->input->post('StuClass') will give you the selected value.

Hope this helps.